# Emacs theme not covering up the entire terminal window. The Ubuntu purple terminal background is showing on the edges

Tags: emacs, emacs24

At the bottom of the screen when emacs is open there is a strip of purple, meaning that emacs in terminal isnt maximizing to the full size that the terminal window allows and thus the background from the terminal is showing.  I know this is nit-picky but my OCD is driving me crazy.  Anyway to fix this?

I would post an image but I don't have enough stackoverflow karma points yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to another SE site: emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: My bad.  Can I just delete and repost there?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you might try setting the fringe color. I usually match mine to the background color with with this:

```
;; regardless of the theme, match the fringe the default background
(set-face-background 'fringe (face-attribute 'default :background))
```